# How to add a self-defined malloc to the Linux

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system, malloc

I want to add a self-defined malloc function(such as, '**self_malloc()**') and a selection function(such as '**selec_malloc()**')  to the Linux operating system.

Every time when a process needs to invoke malloc for memory alloction, the operating system will **invoke selec_malloc() to decide to invoke original malloc or the  self_malloc()**

That is to say, i want to **add a selection function**  **before malloc is invoked**. So is there some way to achieve this and what i need to do?

Hoping for your help.

Comment: Do you want to do this for your own program, or to intercept memory allocations by other running programs on the same system?

Comment: Don't know if there is an official way to do it. But you could probably patch and recompile the c-runtimelibrary on your system. (glibc)

Comment: `malloc` is not provided by the OS (Linux) as a system call, but is implemented by the C standard library.

Comment: Only for my own program. But is there some way to make it becoming a behavior at the **operating system level**, that is to say every process in the system will invoke the  selection function?

Comment: It sounds like you forgot `self_free`. This is far more problematic, because the decision to invoke `self_free` must _exactly_ match the _corresponding_ decision of `selec_malloc`. Glibc's `free()` will very likely corrupt its heap if you pass it the return value of `self_malloc`.

Comment: So, should I self define all the functions in the malloc family ?

Answer (score 1):

malloc is not part of Linux but is part of libc. You may provide your own version of libc with a different malloc implementation. In this case you can switch between the different malloc versions by switching the library search path.

Another option is using LD_PRELOAD. This pre-loads a shared library when starting a program. By this you can overload functions from shared libs with versions in the pre-loaded library. You can even call the original version from within your code using dlsym and RTLD_NEXT like this:

```
typedef void *(*malloc_ptr)(size_t size);

void *malloc(size_t size) {
     malloc_ptr _malloc;
     _malloc=(malloc_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"malloc"); // look up original malloc()
     return malloc_(size);                          // and invoke it
}
```

Selection which malloc version is used depends on the existence of LD_PRELOAD. If it is set, the pre-loaded malloc will be used, if it is not set, the standard version would be used.

Invoking a program looks like this:

```
LD_PRELOAD=libmymalloc.so ./a.out
```